# Automatically doubling the value of numbers in a string in multiple files

Tags: command-line, java, grep, sed, awk

I'm trying to modify Java source code in numerous `.java` files that contain strings similar to this:

```
private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height(0.1F, 0.2F);
```

There are over 75 and I'd like to find a way to automate the **doubling of the 0.1F and 0.2F values** in multiple strings. **Note that the 0.1F and 0.2F values are different in each file.**

For example, in one file, the string may be this:

```
private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height(0.2F, 0.1F);
```

In which case, I'd like it to be:

```
private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height(0.4F, 0.2F);
```

How can I automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `perl` e.g.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=Height\()([0-9.]+)F(.+?)([0-9.]+)F(?=\);)/sprintf "%sF%s%sF",2*$1,$2,2*$3/e' file.java
```

The `(?<=Height\()` and `(?=\);)` are [zero-length assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or *lookarounds* that limit the matches to the specific region between those delimiters, after which the numeric values are extracted using [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) whose values `$1`...`$3` can then be manipulated in the replacement expression using `sprintf` with the `/e` (evaluate) modifier.

To apply recursively, you could use the `find` command e.g.

```
find . -name '*.java' -execdir perl -i'.bak' -pe 's/(?<=Height\()([0-9.]+)F(.+?)([0-9.]+)F(?=\);)/sprintf "%sF%s%sF",2*$1,$2,2*$3/e' {} \;
```

---

Running it on your test file:

```
$ perl -i'.bak' -pe 's/(?<=Height\()([0-9.]+)F(.+?)([0-9.]+)F(?=\);)/sprintf "%sF%s%sF",2*$1,$2,2*$3/e' bop.txt
```

then using `diff` to confirm the replacement

```
$ diff bop.txt.bak bop.txt
12c12
<   private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height(8.0F, 0.025F);
---
>   private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height(16F, 0.05F);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but this doesn't seem to be working either. Here is a link to one of the files: http://pastebin.com/GmKvyp2M

Comment: @A.J.Ruckman it works for me: see edit

Comment: Another question: If I just wanted to double the second value (0.025F in the example), how would I do that?

Comment: @A.J.Ruckman with minimal modification, you could simply change the replacement expression to `sprintf "%sF%s%sF",$1,$2,2*$3` (strictly speaking, there's no longer a need to capture the first group, so it could be made simpler)

Answer (score 3):

I assume all lines you want to change start with the string `private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height`. If yes, then you can use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[(,)]' '$1=="private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height"\
{$0=$1"("$2*2"F, "$3*2"F);";}1' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F'[(,)]'` sets `awk`'s delimiter to the characters `(`, `)` and `,` that we have the paramters of that java function in the `awk` fields $`2` and `$3`
- `$1=="..."` if the first field equals the string

  - `{$0=$1"("$2*2"F, "$3*2"F);";}` reformat the new string with the doubled values.
- `1`, that single `1` at the end is equivalent to `{print $0}`, hence print the whole (edited or not edited) line.

**Edit:**

The above `awk` statement only works when the line start exactly with `private static ...`. When there are spaces we need to change it a bit:

```
awk -F'[(,)]' '$1~/[ ]*private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height/\
{$0=$1"("$2*2"F, "$3*2"F);";}1'
```

I checked with your [pasted code](http://pastebin.com/GmKvyp2M). See the `diff`:

```
$ diff file_old file_new
12c12
<       private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height(8.0F, 0.025F);
---
>       private static final Height biomeHeight = new Height(16F, 0.05F);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is one of the files: http://pastebin.com/GmKvyp2M

Comment: @A.J.Ruckman see my edit, tested it with your code, should work now.

Comment: Hi, your answer worked too but unfortunately I can't choose both. Sorry!

Comment: @chaos you could also improve the answer by [writing back to same file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019617/how-to-write-finding-output-to-same-file-using-awk-command) because by itself the command writes only to stdout. Meanwhile , +1 for awk version =)